How to get access to android notification pop-up style using react native
I would like to know if there is any way to modify "notification pop-up style" from 'brief' to 'detailed'.
I am using Notifee to create push messages on the app, and I would like to make sure the user reads full text of the push message. If notification pop-up style is set the brief, the notification banner which appears under status bar becomes very small. (please check the image attached.)
enter image description here
I tried setting Notification Importance High and setting notification category to CALL
const = displayNotification = async() => {
    await notifee.displayNotification({
        title:'test',
        body:'test test'
        android:{
            channelId:'alarm'
            importance:AndroidImportance.HIGH, // this allows pop up when app is on foreground
            category: AndroidCategory.CALL,
        }
    })
}

Yes, setting android category to CALL would show the 'detailed' pop-up style, but I know this is not the best way, as the notification is not related to calling.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

What about ALARM category? This might differ from device to device. Interesting that the specification says that the category has no visual impact: https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/androidcategory.

I know, on the doc, it says that the category has no visual impact, but actually it does... and only setting it to CALL works! I want something other than using category, but it seems there is no other way...
